# Can't get color output in Node

Tags: node.js, macos, colors, terminal, chalk

I'm trying to log to the console in different colors using [`chalk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) but I haven't gotten it to work. I have a file that consists of the following two lines and I'm running it with the command `node test.js`

```
var chalk = require('chalk');
console.log(chalk.red('Hello'));
// outputs 'hello' in black
```

The following command does output in red so I know that it's possible in my terminal.

```
node <<< "console.log('\x1b[31mhello\x1b[m')"
```

I have `"chalk": "^2.1.0"` in my dev dependencies and have run a `npm install`. The following shows some of my setup.

```
$ node --version
v8.2.1

$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ echo $TERM_PROGRAM
Apple_Terminal
```

Any ideas?

---

**Additionally:**

It looks like `chalk` isn't outputting the ansi codes at all for some reason...

```
console.log(util.inspect('hello'));
//'hello'
console.log(util.inspect(chalk.red('hello')));
// 'hello'
console.log(util.inspect('\x1b[31mhello\x1b[m'));
// '\u001b[31mhello\u001b[m'
```

Comment: For those working with Turbo, try this npm package as a chalk alternative, visit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/turbocolor/v/2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue. This answer is for anyone else in the future.

Turns out that chalk won't apply styles if you are piping the output somewhere.

In my npm scripts, I was using:

`node export.js | tee export.log`

Since I was switching to use Winston for logging anyway, and it can output to different files via 'transports', I no longer need the output piped somewhere and chalk is free to work.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Same issue here. I had `| grep -v ...` on the end of a script. Removed and now I see the colours. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it works locally. But it doesn't work on the **CICD** pipeline.

The solution is to set the following **environment variable** of your CICD pipeline:

`FORCE_COLOR=1`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the package fixed the problem.

```
npm remove -D chalk
```

```
npm i -D chalk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

```bash
npm install chalk@4.1.2
```